# Printing Columns in C

Tags: c

There are similar questions asked, but none that help me arrive at the answer I'm looking for, so I've come to ask for help!

Also, this is homework so I am looking for an explanation more so than just working code.

I need to print two, or maybe its four, columns of output to display the factorials for the numbers 1-20.

I'm pretty close, I just can't seem to figure out how to get these two pieces to be side by side.

Code:

```
lngFactorial = 1;

// Factorials 1 - 10
for (intIndex = 1; intIndex <=10; intIndex += 1)
{

    lngFactorial *= intIndex;
    printf("%d! = %-20lu \n", intIndex, lngFactorial );
}

// Factorials 11 - 20
for (intIndex = 11; intIndex <= 20; intIndex += 1)
{
    lngFactorial *= intIndex;
    printf("%20d ! = %lu \n", intIndex, lngFactorial);
}
```

Output:

```
1! = 1
2! = 2
3! = 6
4! = 24
5! = 120
6! = 720
7! = 5040
8! = 40320
9! = 362880
10! = 3628800
              11 ! = 39916800
              12 ! = 479001600
              13 ! = 1932053504
              14 ! = 1278945280
              15 ! = 2004310016
              16 ! = 2004189184
              17 ! = 4006445056
              18 ! = 3396534272
              19 ! = 109641728
              20 ! = 2192834560
```

So, is this 4 columns and I need to figure out somehow to to print

```
1! = 1    11! = 39961800
```

Or am I just missing something in my printf?

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: You have to print columns 1 and 11 at the same time.

Comment: `13!` is not equal to `1932053504`

Comment: @Stargateur - looks like integer overflow to me.  `13! == 0x17328CC00`.  Whereas `x7328CC00 == 1932053504`.  OP needs to switch from `int` to `long long` for all his calculations and use `%ll` for the format parameter to printf instead of `%d`.

Comment: Ah, good to know!  I will change it from an unsigned long to an unsigned long long, thank you for this!  Could you elaborate on what you mean by " 13! == 0x17328CC00. Whereas x7328CC00 == 1932053504" ?

Comment: @user3691838 - `13!` is `6227020800` (as base 10).  In base 16 (hexadecimal) this is written out as 9 hex digits: `17328CC00` where each digit represents 4-bits.  Hence a 32-bit number can't be more than 8 hex digits.  And so when you have overflow, the result is computed as `overflow % 2^32`, which is equivalent to dropping the leading digit from that 9-digit hex string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Print columns together, something like

```
// Using long long to allow big numbers and to prevent overflow.
unsigned long long lngFactorial1 = 1;
unsigned long long lngFactorial2 = 3628800;// 10!
for (intIndex = 1; intIndex <= 10; intIndex++) {
    lngFactorial1 *= intIndex;
    lngFactorial2 *= intIndex + 10;
    printf("%d! = %-20llu ; %d! = %-20llu;\n", intIndex, lngFactorial1, intIndex + 10, lngFactorial2);
}
```

Comment: This.  It didn't cross my mind to initialize a second factorial with the output at 10.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Once you are using a newline character, you can not go back to the previous line (without changing it).

If you need 1! and 11! in the same line they must be printed in one line and then a newline character. So, for a particular iteration i and (10+i) factorials will be printed. (1<=i<=10).

Also, for storing factorials over 12, you will need long data type.

Comment: Newline is not an "operator", it's just a character. I think it's a bit confusing to call it an operator.

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to printf to look something like this

```
printf("%d! = %-20lu "%20d ! = %lu", intIndex, lngFactorialn, (intIndex + 10), lngFactorialn);
```

so you need to calculate these first and then print them at the same time.
I think this should do the trick with just one for loop.

Comment: You have to create 2 variables for factorial as current depends on previous.

Comment: I think this is the solution because, the for goes from 1 to 10 and the second  from 11 to 20, and he need this to be in one row, and knowing this is homework, the teacher thought that the student should think of that .

Comment: But look at your values. Values for 11 depends on value from 10 from previous loop. Which means your output has wrong result.

Comment: That's what I was missing, I kept trying something similar to this figuring out if it all needed to be on one line or not, but I kept getting the wrong results.

Comment: @user3691838 you didn't check my answer?

Comment: @tilz0R you are right, i wrote this out of my head didn't really think it through.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers mention you have to calculate the same rows in each columns simultaneously. Here is my solution which works for various column numbers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void factorial_in_columns(int col_num, int width, int max_fact) {
    int col_width = width / col_num; /* the width of a column */
    int fact_offset = max_fact / col_num; /* calculation distance */

    char col_buffer[col_width]; /* buffer of a column */
    char line_buffer[width + 1]; /* buffer of a line */

    long factorial;
    int i, j, k, x, len;

    for(i = 1; i <= fact_offset; ++i) {
        for(j = 0; j < col_num; ++j) {
            x = (i + (j * fact_offset)); /* current number */

            for(factorial = 1, k = 1; k <= x; ++k)
                factorial *= k;

            /* convert the result to string and append it to the line buffer */
            snprintf(col_buffer, col_width, "%d = %ld", x, factorial);
            sprintf(line_buffer + (col_width * j), "%-*s", col_width, col_buffer);
        }            
        printf("%s\n", line_buffer);
    }
}

int main() {
    factorial_in_columns(4, 120, 20);
    return 0;
}
```